# OpenGL - Vertex Array inside a VBO and Index & Texture Array outside?

Tags: opengl, vbo

Is it possible to place a set of Vertices into a VBO, but take the Index and Texture coord. Arrays from regular memory? If yes, which syntax to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this. But you shouldn't.

The reason to use buffer objects is to improve performance. Doing what you suggest simply reduces the performance you would have gained by properly using buffer objects.

Also, it's a driver path that most drivers don't see very often. Either people use buffer objects for vertex data, or they use client memory arrays. Since it's a road less traveled, you're more likely to encounter driver bugs.

The syntax is just the regular syntax. The `gl*Pointer` calls use buffer objects or not based on whether a buffer object is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` *at the time the `gl*Pointer` call is made*. As such, you can bind a buffer to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, make a `gl*Pointer` call with an offset, then bind 0 to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and make a `gl*Pointer` call with an actual pointer.

Similarly, the `glDraw*Elements*` calls use a buffer object if a buffer is bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. So if you want to use client memory for these functions, bind 0 to that.

Comment: In addition to this quite good answer: You can always set a usage of `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` or `GL_STREAM_DRAW` if your texCoord and index buffers' data changes frequently. If this was the reason you wanted them to be sourced from CPU memory.

Comment: That is indeed my objective. But the problem is - I cannot stream that much of memory into the buffer object each frame without loosing performance. (I would have to restream it several hundred times before swap buffer). My idea was to place the vertices into GPU memory since these are never updated and create all sets of indices and texture coord. in RAM (since it is much larger then GPU memory). That way I do not need to copy any memory each frame at all - I just can pick the right array in regular memory as needed.

Comment: Would it be more convenient and maybe performing faster, if I placed all of the data in CPU and did not use VBO at all?

Comment: @Fejwin: If you are rendering so much vertex data that streaming breaks down for you, why do you think that the driver (which has to DMA it from your client arrays) will be able to do a better job? Are you [streaming correctly](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming)? Also, you should test it yourself to see if it gives better performance.

Comment: Wow! "streaming correctly" is a very useful link, thank you! One last thing I am curious about: I learned that extensive binding of different textures has negative impact on performance. Is the extensive binding of different VBOs comparable to that performance loss or is it essentially "free"?

Comment: @Fejwin: Binding to modify a buffer object is "free" (to the extent that the modifications are "free"). Binding to _use_ one is not.